# .NET Core conserve bitmap resolution when returning file

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm working on a web service in .Net Core 2.1.

This service return a bitmap, there is my code :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GenBitmap")]
public ActionResult GetItem(int PrintPPI = 300)
{
    try
    {
        FileContentResult result;
        using (Bitmap bmp = genBitmap(PrintPPI))
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                result = new FileContentResult(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        return new ContentResult
        {
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
            Content = $"Status Code: {StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError}; {StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError}; {exc.Message}",
            ContentType = "text/plain",
        };
    }
}

private Bitmap genBitmap(int printppi)
{
    // My code use some libraries, so I changed it
    // The code below generate a random image
    // The new bitmap is generated in the same way, only rawMsg is different from my code
    int w = 50;
    int h = 50;

    int size = h * w;
    Byte[] rawMsg = new byte[size];
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < rawMsg.Length; i++)
        rawMsg[i] = (Byte)rnd.Next(256);

    // Generate bitmap
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    bmp.SetResolution(printppi, printppi);
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            byte pixValue = rawMsg[y * w + x];
            Color c = Color.FromArgb(pixValue, pixValue, pixValue);
            bmp.SetPixel(x, y, c);
        }
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

When I do `genBitmap`, my `bmp` as his resolution to `PrintPPI`. but when I get the image from the web service, the resolution has changed.

I've try with different values for `PrintPPI`, the `bmp` resolution is correctly setted but the result has always the same resolution.

How can I conserve the resolution when I convert my bitmap to a png `FileContentResult` ?

Comment: What is genBitmap?

Comment: @John sorry it was a typo, genBitmap is the method called by my httpGet.

Comment: I'm wondering what your goal is here. A 50x50 pixel image at 300 PPI is going to be pretty small (1/6 inch wide). Is that what you want?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen That's is just a synthesis of my code, `genBitmap` generate image with some library that I can not provide here (usually images 250x250) and users must be able to change ppi.

Comment: You can use `return StatusCode(500,....)` to return an error message.

Comment: @A.Pissicat how do you call that action? If you debug this code, what's the value of the `PrintPPI ` action parameter? I suspect there's a problem with parameter binding and all bitmaps use the default PrintPPI value

Comment: You can try saving to a temporary file instead of `MemoryStream` and check the temporary file's resolution. `FileContentResult` doesn't know anything about its contents, it just sends the contents of a file/stream/buffer and the content type

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I checked the bmp resolution, it is correctly set. So I saved the bmp in a temporary file and with different ppi, all files get the same size. So I opened a microsoft word document and paste bmp with different ppi and then, size are different ! But I don't understand why I can't see differences with other viewer ?

Comment: @A.Pissicat Word isn't a graphics tool. [Image files have no resolution](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107888/check-dpi-of-png-file) anyway. As the answers from `graphicdesign.stackexchange.com` show, DPI/PPI matter when you want to use physical dimensions (cm/inches)

Comment: Check [The Myth of DPI](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/02/the-myth-of-dpi/) which explains how pixel density is used, that it doesn't matter for the web and only comes into play when printing. Formats like PNG/GIF discard that information